# Getting updates of okular pdf reader in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, kde, okular

I am currently using Version 0.24.2 of okular reader and want to update it to its latest version (1.0). I following the standard procedure given on its official site but encountering several problems on building the source code. Can anyone tell me an easier way of updating okular in Ubuntu?

**Error on cmake:**

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/shikhar/Softwares/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5ModuleLocation.cmake:4 (set):
  Policy CMP0053 is not set: Simplify variable reference and escape sequence
  evaluation.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0053" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  For input:

    '${_qt5_install_prefix}/Qt5@module@/Qt5@module@Config.cmake'

  the old evaluation rules produce:

    '/home/shikhar/Softwares/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake'

  but the new evaluation rules produce:

    '/home/shikhar/Softwares/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5@module@/Qt5@module@Config.cmake'

  Using the old result for compatibility since the policy is not set.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/shikhar/Softwares/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:25 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Activities"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5ActivitiesConfig.cmake
    kf5activities-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Activities" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Activities_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Activities" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Activities: found neither KF5ActivitiesConfig.cmake nor kf5activities-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Archive"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5ArchiveConfig.cmake
    kf5archive-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Archive" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Archive_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Archive" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Archive: found neither KF5ArchiveConfig.cmake nor kf5archive-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Bookmarks"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5BookmarksConfig.cmake
    kf5bookmarks-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Bookmarks" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Bookmarks_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Bookmarks" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Bookmarks: found neither KF5BookmarksConfig.cmake nor kf5bookmarks-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Completion"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5CompletionConfig.cmake
    kf5completion-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Completion" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Completion_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Completion" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Completion: found neither KF5CompletionConfig.cmake nor kf5completion-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Config"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5ConfigConfig.cmake
    kf5config-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Config" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Config_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Config" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Config: found neither KF5ConfigConfig.cmake nor kf5config-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5ConfigWidgets"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5ConfigWidgetsConfig.cmake
    kf5configwidgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5ConfigWidgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "KF5ConfigWidgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "KF5ConfigWidgets" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5ConfigWidgets: found neither KF5ConfigWidgetsConfig.cmake nor kf5configwidgets-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5CoreAddons"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake
    kf5coreaddons-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5CoreAddons" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5CoreAddons_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5CoreAddons" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5CoreAddons: found neither KF5CoreAddonsConfig.cmake nor kf5coreaddons-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5DBusAddons"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5DBusAddonsConfig.cmake
    kf5dbusaddons-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5DBusAddons" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5DBusAddons_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5DBusAddons" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5DBusAddons: found neither KF5DBusAddonsConfig.cmake nor kf5dbusaddons-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5DocTools"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5DocToolsConfig.cmake
    kf5doctools-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5DocTools" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5DocTools_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5DocTools" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5DocTools: found neither KF5DocToolsConfig.cmake nor kf5doctools-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5IconThemes"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5IconThemesConfig.cmake
    kf5iconthemes-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5IconThemes" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5IconThemes_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5IconThemes" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5IconThemes: found neither KF5IconThemesConfig.cmake nor kf5iconthemes-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5JS" (requested
  version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5JSConfig.cmake
    kf5js-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5JS" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5JS_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "KF5JS"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5JS: found neither KF5JSConfig.cmake nor kf5js-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5KIO" (requested
  version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5KIOConfig.cmake
    kf5kio-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5KIO" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5KIO_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "KF5KIO"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5KIO: found neither KF5KIOConfig.cmake nor kf5kio-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Parts"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5PartsConfig.cmake
    kf5parts-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Parts" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Parts_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Parts" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Parts: found neither KF5PartsConfig.cmake nor kf5parts-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5ThreadWeaver"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5ThreadWeaverConfig.cmake
    kf5threadweaver-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5ThreadWeaver" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "KF5ThreadWeaver_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "KF5ThreadWeaver" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5ThreadWeaver: found neither KF5ThreadWeaverConfig.cmake nor kf5threadweaver-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5Wallet"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5WalletConfig.cmake
    kf5wallet-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5Wallet" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5Wallet_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5Wallet" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5Wallet: found neither KF5WalletConfig.cmake nor kf5wallet-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5KHtml"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5KHtmlConfig.cmake
    kf5khtml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5KHtml" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "KF5KHtml_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "KF5KHtml" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5KHtml: found neither KF5KHtmlConfig.cmake nor kf5khtml-config.cmake 
CMake Warning at /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "KF5WindowSystem"
  (requested version 5.16.0) with any of the following names:

    KF5WindowSystemConfig.cmake
    kf5windowsystem-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "KF5WindowSystem" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "KF5WindowSystem_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
  If "KF5WindowSystem" provides a separate development package or SDK, be
  sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Could NOT find KF5WindowSystem: found neither KF5WindowSystemConfig.cmake nor kf5windowsystem-config.cmake 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find KF5 (missing: Activities Archive Bookmarks Completion Config
  ConfigWidgets CoreAddons DBusAddons DocTools IconThemes JS KIO Parts
  ThreadWeaver Wallet KHtml WindowSystem) (Required is at least version
  "5.16.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:110 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Use a snap: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/okular-available-snap-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt install kinit-dev libkf5crash-dev libkf5notifications-dev libkf5notifyconfig-dev libkf5parts-dev libkf5kcmutils-dev libkf5newstuff-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5config-dev -y
sudo apt install libkf5activities-dev libphonon4qt5-dev -y
sudo apt install libkf5baloowidgets-dev libkf5filemetadata-dev  libkf5kdelibs4support-dev -y
sudo apt install baloo-kf5-dev -y
```

If it fails, you can try installing the dependencies from KDE project:
https://superuser.com/a/912259/891550